# C# return from base method

Tags: c#, return, overriding, virtual, radix

The code after `base.OnAllyTurnStart();` continues executing even though the base method returns.How can i prevent the execution of code bellow the base method?

```
// BASE METHOD
public virtual void OnAllyTurnStart()
{
    if(// if it is not my turn)
    return;
}


public override void OnAllyTurnStart()
{
    base.OnAllyTurnStart();

    // Code bellow should execute only when it's my turn
    // ..................................
}
```

Comment: If you don't want other code in that method to run, why do you have other code in that method?

Comment: @itsme86: I would guess that code is supposed to run sometimes, but the base implementation has early return logic that should skip all subsequent processing.

Comment: Well the base method is either going to have to set some kind of flag that the overridden method can reference, or start returning a value that can be checked by the overridden method.

Comment: You're only returning out of the base, not the overrided implementation. I would actually suggest a complete rethink of your system. If you're looking for a sloppy and nasty fix though, you could always wrap a bool into a class, and then pass that class as a paramter into the OnAllyTurnStart(). You can then make the bool in the class false, and use it in an if statement in the override to see if the logic should continue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide an indication of early return from the called function to the caller.

You could use a return value, an `out` parameter, or a member on a parameter object (have a look at `CancelEventArgs`).  Then the derived class could check that indication provided by the base implementation and know whether it should continue processing or not.

Or you could throw an exception that is caught by the event source.  Exceptions effectively provide a long jump traversing multiple frames of the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that your override method is not explicitly returning.  This is the same behavior for calling any method without returning.  There is no functional difference between `base.OnAllyTurnStart();` and `Console.WriteLine("foo");` from a control-flow perspective.

I imagine there is a conditional reason you would want to do this.  If the function returns a value you can cascade the return value:

```
public override int OnAllyTurnStart()
{
    // do other work
    return base.OnAllyTurnStart();
}
```

Alternatively, you can early return after calling base.OnAllyTurnStart assuming there is a reason you would want a branch of logic to sometimes do something else:

```
public override voic OnAllyTurnStart()
{
    base.OnAllyTurnStart();
    return;
}
```

This likely only makes sense if there is conditional logic to do additional work.  If your method only did the above you could simply not override the virtual member and instances of the subclass will use the base class' virtual method when called.

Comment: You are right. There is conditional logic which I didn't include for the sake of simplifying the code.I edited my post to include that logic. A solution that came to mind is to just move the conditional logic inside the override. The problem with that solution is that I'd have to include it in every override of the method and I think this will not be such a good coding practice because when i override the method in 10 different derrived classes I essentialy have the same code 10 times.